# PayPal "Thank you" page, with details

Tags: php, paypal

I'm working on setting up a page that will display some information to the end-user after they make a purchase through PayPal. This page will have quite a few different tasks that it will need to execute to ensure the user receives what they had paid for, this mostly includes displaying information for the user in-case something goes seriously wrong, **for example:** The email containing product information is never sent.

In this event I would like to instruct the user to fill out "X" form providing their custom transaction id, however I don't know how I'd pass that custom transaction id to the thank-you page from paypal.

I know how to use the IPN, and I'm rather familliar with it. I've always used it to send emails, etc; However here, considering I'm selling a virtual product, I need to make sure it's delivered automatically, and providing enough information so that any problems can be dealt with accordingly.

Comment: so what's the actual question?

Comment: Depending upon what PayPal product you are using, you can generally get the same information the IPN contains in either the API response or the "Payment Data Transfer" (PDT) postback fields from the redirect if you are using a non-API-based product.

Comment: What are you referring to "custom transaction id" - yours or PayPal's? If the former, then "when" that id is generated will matter. IINM, in most (if not all) cases, you'll need to pass that early on in any Paypal flow. If the latter, the comment above and answer below is it. Hth.

Answer (score 1):

IPN itself is all you need.  You can generate email notifications with a download link or an attachment of the digital item that you're selling and it will be delivered in real-time.  It will also help you handle things like e-checks correctly so that the goods aren't delivered until the payment actually clears as opposed to when the first transaction (the pending e-check) comes through.

If you do want to display data on the thank you page (assuming you're working with Payments Standard) then you can use PDT, which is very similar to IPN except that it's intended to send data back to the thank you page.  This is for display purposes only and is not recommended to be used for updating the database, sending emails, etc.

Yet another option would be to move to the Express Checkout API.  That way the checkout flow will always finish on your site without setting up any auto-return or PDT features, and you can do whatever you need to do in the thank you page code very easily.  Again, though, it's still recommended to use IPN for final post-payment processing so that you can handle things like pending payments.

Comment: Thank you, I'm still using the IPN to take care of all of my logic (Such as database population and sending emails), but I wanted to have a fall-back plan that would show them information generated during the IPN scripts process, just in-case the emails didn't get sent for some reason.